# Error show when update using phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, mariadb

When I update a column using `phpmyadmin` in database with following query

```
UPDATE members
SET `refered` = (SELECT COUNT (*)
                 FROM `user_details`
                 WHERE `user_details.sponser`=`members.username`
                )
```

It show a error message like this

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '*) FROM `user_details` WHERE `user_details.sponser`=`members.username`)' at line 1

What may be reason?

Comment: try UPDATE members
SET `refered` = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                 FROM `user_details`
                 WHERE `user_details.sponser`=`members.username`
                )

Answer (score 0):

Error is in

```
COUNT (*)
-----^
```

Remove the space between `COUNT` and `(*)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try the below query 
UPDATE members SET refered = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_details 
WHERE user_details.sponser=members.username)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the Select query returns any result. If so what is the result. Looks like all your query is inside '' single quotes that you are using it should be removed. Single quotes need to be removed for example .

```
UPDATE members
SET refered = (SELECT COUNT (*)
                 FROM user_details
                 WHERE user_details.sponser=members.username
                )
```

-- there is not single quotes in the query above. please remove it from yours.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem, or maybe the whole problem, is the WHERE clause. You've used backticks for the table name, which is correct (or, at least, it's optional in this case; it's needed if your database name or table name has a MySQL reserved name or is otherwise ambiguous). The problem, though, is that the dot separating the database from the table needs to be outside the backticks. So your WHERE clause should look like this instead:

`` WHERE `user_details`.`sponser`=`members`.`username` ``